# Xslt Matching Elements by attribute via XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="vrtfDoc2">
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="$vrtfDoc2/*"/>

  File 1 TO File 2 MATCH

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:param name="pDoc2"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
        <xsl:with-param name="pDoc2" select="$pDoc2"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Topic/SubTopic/*">
      <xsl:with-param name="pDoc2" select="$vDoc2"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    -----------------------

    File 2 TO File 1 MATCH

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc2">
      <xsl:with-param name="pDoc2" select="/*"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Topic/SubTopic/*">
    <xsl:param name="pDoc2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="guid" select="../@Guid" />
    <table border="1" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <td>Current Element</td>
        <td>Left Guid</td>
        <td>Left</td>
        <td>Right</td>
        <td>Right Guid</td>
        <td>Diff Type</td>
      </thead>

      <xsl:if test="not(. = $pDoc2/*/*[name()=name(current())])">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="$guid"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="$pDoc2/*/*[name()=name(current())]"/>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>Diff</td>
      </tr> 
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test=". = $pDoc2/*/*[name()=name(current())]">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="../@Guid"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="$pDoc2/*/*[name()=name(current())]"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="$pDoc2/*/*[name()=name(current())]"/>
        </td>
        <td>Same</td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In essence the transform file checks equality left to right and then right to left. The only problem is my xml files have snippets similar to

```
  <SubTopic Guid="462AF46304694D4785EF3B7E642AD8A2">
    <Description xmlns="http://www.authorit.com/xml/authorit" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Modification History</Description>
    <Text xmlns="http://www.authorit.com/xml/authorit" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <p id="4">Not Applicable</p>
    </Text>
  </SubTopic>
```

The xslt gives me the differences matching elements by in order from top to bottom but doesn't guarantee that it matching the **CORRECT** element. That it, it is comparing `<SubTopic Guid="462AF46304694D4785EF3B7E642AD8A2">` from the left comparison xml to `<SubTopic Guid="462AF46304694D4785EF3B7E642AD8A2">` in the comparison right xml.

The line

```
<xsl:variable name="guid" select="../@Guid" />
```

gives me the parent guid from the left xml file, which is correct, but I've tried variants on the following

```
<xsl:if test="not(. = $pDoc2/*/*[name()=name(current())][@Guid=$guid])">
```

but that process as if the '[@Guid=$guid]' wasn't there.

In short the xslt must compare the correct elements and it must have t

I know my xslt skills are low but I am sure that I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that `$guid` variable is built using the `../@Guid` (thus the `parent` axes) and then the XPath expression is looking for an equality of names and guids but expect both to match on the same level. maybe it should be converted to `[name() = name(current())][../@Guid = $guid]`? if this is not the case then maybe you can post a simplified version of your input and the expected result? this would help us help you debug the transform. also as a note, the `. =` comparison will test for the equality of the string values of the two nodes. If you expect it to test for the *existence* of a node with the same name and parent Guid then you would need to shorten it to `not($pDoc2/*/*[name()=name(current())][../@Guid=$guid]`